# res.redirect() does not end request and causes error: "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client "

Tags: node.js, express

My route that handles get requests for the login page checks to see if the user is already logged in. If they are, redirect them to /userprofile, if not, render the login.ejs view.

From what I was reading, res.redirect() should end the http request, but in this example I've been getting some weird behavior. When the user is logged in, I get the error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" multiple times. Here's the code:

```
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user) { res.redirect('/userprofile') };
    res.render('login');
})
```

But I realized that if

- I just include a return before res.redirect() or
- negate the if statement and invert the order of the responses

the code works fine.

Could anyone explain why? Thanks

Comment: `res.redirect` sends headers to client, `res.render` also sends headers to client and you `cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

Comment: The answer is already in your question: "If they are, redirect them to /userprofile, if not, render the login.ejs view." - this is an if/else statement, while in your code you only have 1 "if" - where is the "else"? :D After the "redirect", the code continue - that's why you need an "else" or a "return"

Comment: So the code in the function still runs after a response is sent?

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by you redirecting the user, to `/userprofile` before rendering login. A way you could avoid this would be to do the redirect frontend, in your fetch.

```js
fetch('login', {
 method: 'POST',
})
.then(() => {
window.location.href = '/userprofile'
})
```